# How to manage multiple fragments inside single tab

Tags: android, tabs, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock

I want to use multiple fragments inside single tab. my tab activity extends `SherlockFragmentActivity`.

Now i add first fragment for first tab in `onTabChanged()` method. and i replace another fragment from within first fragment in first tab. But no when i go to second tab and then again re-open first tab, state of first tab not maintained and first fragment become visible rather than second fragment of first tab.

I need help for how to maintain stake of fragments within single tab and how to pop up exiting fragment front within single tab.

Any body have idea ?

Comment: Are you using a viewpager ?

Comment: Not now. but i am ready to use it if it is useful and may solve my problem. Please give me hint for the same.

Comment: This is one of my question, the code can help you maybe. I use an adapter to manage the fragments in tabs+viewpager http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17815305/abs-viewpager-manage-orientation-change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using two tabs, you have to maintain two fragments separately for each tab i.e FragmentA for tab1 and FragmentB for tab2 and xmls of FragmentA , FragmentB should have FrameLayout for FrgmentTransaction.

**xml of FragmentA i.e frag_a.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/fragmentA_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

</FrameLayout>
```

and

**xml of FragmentB i.e frag_b.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/fragmentB_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

</FrameLayout>
```

**For Tab1, always do the transaction using R.id.fragmentA_container. i.e replace another fragment from within first fragment(FragmentA) in first tab. like below code**

In FragmentA:

```
Fragment fragment = new YourFragment();
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
fragment.setArguments(null);
ft.replace(R.id.fragmentA_container, fragment);
ft.commit();
```

**For Tab2, always do the transaction using R.id.fragmentB_container. i.e replace another fragment from within secondfragment(FragmentB) in second tab. like below code**

In FragmentB:

```
Fragment fragment = new YourFragment();
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
fragment.setArguments(null);
ft.replace(R.id.fragmentB_container, fragment);
ft.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code for managing multiple fragments in an activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private FragmentManager fragmentManager;
Fragment currentFragment;
Fragment1 initialFragment;
Fragment2 nextFragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
    fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    initialFragment = (Fragment1) fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.initial_fragment);
    nextFragment = (Fragment2) fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.next_fragment);
    nextFragment();
}

public void onNext(View v) {
    // User pressed next button on initial fragment
    showNextFragment();
}

private void showFragment(Fragment fragmentToShow) {
    Fragment[] fragments = { initialFragment, nextFragment /*... */ };
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    for(Fragment fragment : fragments) {
        if(fragment != fragmentToShow) {
            fragmentTransaction.hide(fragment);
        }
    }
    fragmentTransaction.show(fragmentToShow);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}

private void showInitialFragment() {
    currentFragment = initialFragment;
    showFragment(currentFragment);
}

private void showNextFragment() {
    currentFragment = nextFragment;
    showFragment(currentFragment);
}

}
```

Comment: ragmentManager.findFragmentById() always return null. what may be reason ?