# Multiple fragments/layout in one Tab of actionbarsherlock

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, android-viewpager

This is related to my last post, but i need a solution quickly so i'm trying to simplify the problem.

All i want to do i having several fragments (one list at the left and a detail view at the right) in one tab.

Do you have an idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know what the two `Fragment`s are in advance just declar them both within the XML layout file for that tab. You can see how to do this in the [fragment tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html) from the android docs. This will display two fragments in one activity using an outer layout element as a container.

Comment: My app use tabadapter + view pager :  ONE activity SEVERAL fragments tab. What i want is to replace one fragment/tab by the correct layout in ccordance to the oriantation of the device and the type (handset/tablet) i need some guidance because i have no idea how to do this. using layout and layout-land can help but the problem is still here. Either i declare the tab/fragment in xml <fragment> and i can't replace them in the code either i declare some <FrameLayout> so i can replace it with FragmentTransaction but where ?...

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by where? If you're going to add them using the `FrameLayout` then the `FrameLayout` is in your hosting activity. The fragments are selected by the tabs and, when screen size changes you adapt the fragments accordingly. Are you not understanding how to adjust for the size/orientation change? That's a different question.

Comment: My last post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17815305/abs-viewpager-manage-orientation-change / one tab = one fragment + his layout / that is what i what to change

Comment: Ok - I think I understand now. [check out this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13816442/viewpager-with-one-page-containing-multiple-fragments-java-lang-illegalargument) it shows how to put multiple fragments within one page of a viewpager. If you combine that with the tab tutorial you linked to you should be able to solve this problem.